# How to achieve deprecated CompositeView functionality in Marionette 3+?

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette, underscore.js-templating

As stated in the latest [Marionette docs](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.0.0-pre.2/marionette.compositeview.html):

> `CompositeView` is deprecated. You should use the `replaceElement` option on `Region.show` and
>   render a `CollectionView` into a region inside a `View` to achieve this functionality.

I still can't understand how `CompositeView` functionality should be achieved now.

Previously, `CompositeView` was perfect for using with such template:

```
<script id="table-template" type="text/html">
<table>
  <% if (items.length) { %>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 <% } %>

  <tbody></tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">some footer information</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

```
new MyCompositeView({
  template: "#table-template",
  templateContext: function() {
    return { items: this.collection.toJSON() };
  }
  // ... other options
});
```

If we decide to use `LayoutView` instead of `CompositeView` then we need to code manually a lot of event bindings (for example to show / hide table header based on number of items in collection). This makes things harder.

*Are there any clean and not complicated ways to live without `CompositeView`?*

---

Thank you for any help or advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Marionette 3 is going to get rid of some concepts to make the framework simpler overall, and easier to understand.

Marionette.View in 3 is going to include functionality from what was ItemView and LayoutView. CompositeView is deprecated in favour of just using RegionManager, which is now included into View.

```
v2 --> v3
View -> AbstractView  
ItemView, LayoutView -> View
```

Here's a quick example app:

```js
var color_data = [ { title:'red' }, { title:'green' }, { title:'blue' } ];

var Color = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: { title: '' }
});

var Colors = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Color
});

var ColorView = Mn.View.extend({
  tagName: 'tr',
  template: '#colorTpl'
});

var ColorsView = Mn.CollectionView.extend({
  tagName: 'tbody',
  childView: ColorView
});

var AppView = Mn.View.extend({
  template: '#appTpl',
  templateContext: function(){
    return {
      items: this.collection.toJSON()
    };
  },
  ui: {
    input: '.input'
  },
  regions: {
    list: {
      selector: 'tbody',
      replaceElement: true
    },
  },
  onRender: function(){
    this.getRegion('list').show(new ColorsView({
      collection: this.collection
    }));
  },
  events: {
    'submit form': 'onSubmit'
  },
  onSubmit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.collection.add({
      title: this.ui.input.val()
    });
    this.ui.input.val('');
  }
});

var appView = new AppView({
  collection: new Colors(color_data)
});
appView.render().$el.appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src='http://libjs.surge.sh/jquery2.2.2-underscore1.8.3-backbone1.3.2-radio1.0.4-babysitter0.1.11-marionette3rc1.js'></script>

<script id="colorTpl" type="text/template">
  <td><%=title%></td>
  <td style="background-color:<%=title%>">&nbsp;</td>
</script>

<script id="appTpl" type="text/template">
<table width="100%">
  <% if(items.length) { %>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="1%">Title</th>
        <th>Color</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <% } %>
  <tbody></tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <form><input type="text" class="input" autofocus><input type="submit" value="Add Color"></form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

  
</script>
```

Comment: Great, thank you a lot for amazing example! It solves the issue.

Comment: Finally I discovered that there is no such option `replaceElement: true` in Marionette. Why are you using it?

Comment: Jamesh, we are talking about Marionette v3, and `replaceElement` option [is recommended for use instead of CompositeView](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.0.0-pre.2/marionette.compositeview.html). It [might not be entirely supported](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/2957) yet, but your statement is incorrect.

Comment: `replaceElement: true` is required to achieve behaviour similar to the childViewContainer in CompositeView. Otherwise the region would be a container itself by default, which would be one extra element in your DOM tree. Default region behaviour would make it harder in examples like this one, in a table, which is sensitive to the structure of DOM elements.

Comment: my apologies. I was thinking `replaceElement: true` is not available yet in Marionette 3. But that was wrong and your answer is fully correct! Thank you once more.